# Регулярное выражение для номера телефона

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Всем привет. Нужно сделать шаблон на ЯП Python для проверки номера телефона на валидность. При этом шаблон должен отсеивать всё кроме цифр. Желательно чтобы шаблон не пропускал номера, длинее 12 символов.

До этого пытался сделать, но мозгов хватило только на это:
`(\+7|7|8).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{2}).?(\d{2})`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: к примеру тут https://www.regextester.com/99415 дают такой вариант: ^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$